# Attach legacy feed to new Xively interface

Tags: xively

Is there a way to use the legacy feeds in the new development system?  Or, do I have to create new feeds and go through the entire process?  What about moving the data from the existing legacy feeds to the new system?

Comment: Your legacy feeds should have their own workbench but feel free to email support if they are not working.

Comment: For copying the data between feeds see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326119/copy-range-of-historical-datapoints-between-xively-channels